# remove() function in c giving an error?

Tags: c

The following function takes a name and deletes that name from a binary file named All.bin.
As far as i know, it works fine but the remove function always gives an error

```
 void del(char *name)
    {
        struct database d; //strucutre variable containing name and meaning
        FILE *p, *q;
        p = fopen("All.bin","r"); //original file
        q = fopen("temp.bin","w"); // temp file
        while(fread(&d,sizeof(d),1,p))
            if(strcmp(d.name,name) != 0)
                fwrite(&d,sizeof(d),1,q);
        fclose(p);
        fclose(q);
        if(remove("All.bin")!=0) //PROBLEM
            printf("Error");
        if(rename("temp.bin","All.bin")!=0)
            printf("Error@");
        getch();
    }
```

Comment: Use `perror` instead of `printf` to find out what happens.

Comment: What exact error are you getting?

Comment: You should probably be more explicit about opening the files in binary mode.

Comment: You don't even check the return values from the fopen() calls.  This is in need of some additional error checking.

Comment: perror says Error:Permission Denied

Comment: @rohan013 Then you don't have write permission on the file (which is needed for removing it).

Comment: @H2CO3 On what system is that true? On POSIX systems you need write permission on the directory; the file's permissions are irrelevant. On Windows NTFS file systems, you need Modify permission on the file.

Comment: @JimBalter Only for directories? I didn't know that. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @H2CO3 The directory is what is written -- to remove the name/inode entry -- so that's where you need the write permission. Deleting a file from a directory doesn't delete the file unless the inode reference count goes to 0. Also, On NTFS, Modify permission is different from Write permission.

Comment: @JimBalter Yeah, that's quite logical indeed.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me. Change your file permissions after Creating the All.bin file

Answer (score 0):

Check the file permission for All.bin , and also try unlink() function.

If the All.bin is generated by the same process(say the function u call might work once but not after that) , then you need to check on closing the handle for the file stream in your case fclose().